# WinSCP for android

Tags: applications, root-access

Is it possible to transfer files to my Fire Tv Stick with the ES FILE EXPLORER.
Is it necessary to root my fire tv stick first?
This is not possible with fire tv stick because you cant enable root explorer﻿

Comment: What do you need root for there? ES has built-in support for network access, so you can use it to download files via FTP, SCP, even SMB (Windows shares). Assuming ES is installed on that Fire stick, which you don't say.

Comment: ah so if you have ES install on your fire stick you can transfer files with the FTP, SCP with out rooting your fire stick?

Comment: Sure. You can use ES to browse remote resources and download from/upload to those.

Comment: Anytime! I've summed it up in an answer for you. If that solved your issue, please tick the check-mark next to it so it's shown as working solution. Enjoy!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you already use *ES File Explorer* on your *Fire Tv Stick*, you can use that directly to access network resources. The app supports multiple protocols, a.o. FTP, SCP and SMB – but also cloud resources such as Dropbox and SkyDrive.

[image: ES LAN] [image: ES LAN Search] [image: ES LAN credentials]
<sup>*ES File Explorer:* LAN access (source: [CNET](http://www.cnet.com/how-to/share-files-between-android-and-windows-with-es-file-explorer/); click images for larger variants)</sup>

Once set up, you can use that to browse remote resources, and exchange files with them.